# asp.net MVC "Add View" wizard won't pre-populate fields when using a ViewModel

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2010, mvvm

In VS 2010, When you use the "Add View" wizard to create an Edit view with a strongly typed view, such as Models.Person, the template generates all of Person fields for you.

If you use a view model instead, like this:

```
public class PersonVM
{
   public Person person;
   public List<Team> TeamList = new TeamServices().TeamPickList();
   ...
}
```

the template wont create all of the fields for Model.person.

Is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not automatically.

Easiest method is to create a new View, select `Team` as the view data class, Select 'List' as the view content.  Then you could cut and paste the markup generated from this view into the one you have already created.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say I want an Edit view.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the List template it will normally create a table and iterate over an IEnumerable Model. You can also use one of the helpers and/or custom templates in your CodeTemplates folder:

```
<% Html.DisplayForModel(); %>
```

If you need to edit:

```
<% Html.EditorForModel(); %>
```

If you're having trouble with the list, maybe start with one of the helpers?

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TeamList, new SelectList(Model.TeamList)) %>
```